# Add ".cs file" under ContextMenu -> New

Tags: windows, context-menu, right-click

How can I add a "C# File (.cs)" option under the Windows context menu : `Right-click` -> `New`?

I've tried editing the registry, and creating a new key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cs\ShellNew` and adding a "NullFile" String value in it, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

You need a file (which acts as the template for the future 'new' actions) in the ShellNew directory, typically in `C:\Windows\ShellNew` - in addition to the registry entry.  See the summary in [this post](http://forums.cnet.com/7726-12546_102-5046514.html).

To be more explicit, your registry entry (in the location you indicated, but key name of 'Filename') points to the template file you drop into ShellNew.